# Syntax for defining MultiJob conditional step in Job DSL plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

I using [Jenkins CI](https://jenkins-ci.org/) with Job DSL and Multijob plugins. I'm attempting to define a parametrized Multijob containing conditional step using DSL, but I fail to figure out the correct syntax. My code:

```
multiJob("MyJob")
{
    parameters {
        stringParam("PLATFORM", "Win32")
        stringParam("CONFIGURATION", "Release")
    }

    steps
    {
        phase("Build") {
            job("BuildJob") { sameNode() }
        }

        conditionalSteps {
            condition {
                and { stringsMatch("${PLATFORM}", "Win32", false) } { stringsMatch("${CONFIGURATION}", "Release", false) }
            }
            runner('Fail')
            steps {
                phase("Prepare installer") {
                    job("PrepareInstallerJob") { sameNode() }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Running this I get the following error:

```
Processing DSL script My.groovy
ERROR: (My.groovy, line 117) No such property: PLATFORM for class: javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.step.RunConditionContext
Finished: FAILURE
```

When line 117 is the line containing the "and" condition.

What would be the correct syntax? Why does not it resolve the PLATFORM parameter?

Comment: I assume you want it to resolve that parameter at build time? If so, the answer below is absolutely what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Groovy interpolates double quoted strings, see [String interpolation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_string_interpolation). You need to use single quotes to avoid the interpolation, e.g. `'${PLATFORM}'`.